# Is there a way to disable/override the default style for disabled WebControls

Tags: asp.net, themes, styles

that one has been nagging me ever since I dabbled in web developpement; is there a way for this?  Could I override that style and rely on some other mean to inform my users that that control can't be ineracted with?

My problem is that the graying of RadioButton- and CheckBox-Lists' labels makes them unreadable.

I could always replace the disabled TextBoxes with Labels styled/themed to look like TextBoxes, but that'd be more invasive...

[EDIT] Ok, sorry; that's not a solution; TextBoxes already have the "Readonly" option, which means they look the way I want them to, even when locked from user-input; the problem rather lies with IList Controls (RadioButtonLists and CheckBoxLists.)

As ever, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! What it sounds like you're looking for is a [CSS attribute selector](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_attribute.htm):

```
input[@disabled=true], input[@disabled] {
  .. insert your new style here ..
}
```

Hope that helps!